# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Operation must use an updateable query ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Why I have the exception in VS2017 when I am trying to update a table 
`OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = database.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"`

```
"UPDATE `Cars` SET `company` = (SELECT `id` FROM `Companies` WHERE `Companies`.`company` = parameter_company) WHERE `id` = parameter_id"
```

Comment: Did you try to run that query through the MS-Access query processor interface?

Comment: Does C# require the apostrophes for field names? Try without.